# How to convert string to uuid

Tags: c++

I've tried this method,But I got problem in types conversion.

```
unsigned char uuid[] = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";
UUID uid;
UuidFromString(uuid, &uid);
```

My question is : How can i use this function??Or is there any other way to get UUID from string?

Comment: Please elaborate on the problems. Is it a compiler error? If so, please provide the full text of the error in your question.

Comment: Do you have your own class/structure UUID? If you do then can you show it to us? If you don't then which compiler/platform do you use?

Comment: @Grzegorz, Judging by the function, it's [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379358(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Chris - thank you. PsykOoO - what problem in types conversion to you see? Based on the `UuidFromString` definition your code is perfectly correct.

Comment: I get this error  cannot convert argument 1 from 'unsigned char [37]' to 'RPC_WSTR'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
unsigned char uuid[] = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";
UUID uid;
UuidFromStringA(uuid, &uid);
```

`